# bootpag is not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootpag

I'm trying to use a library called [bootpag](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-simple) for pagination, and I'm trying to run an example on jsfiddle. However, it does not seem to be rendering correctly and I don't know what's caused this issue. Why is the bootpag div not rendering correctly, and how do I fix it?

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lsp76eg/3/)

Relevant part of code:

```
$('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading...
});
```

Comment: Are you request help with your code? Or making your code work on jsfiddle?

Comment: Making the code work in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with calling the bootpag code from the raw github link. If you add the code directly into an editor, it functions as expected.

```js
/*

 bootpag - jQuery plugin for dynamic pagination

 Copyright (c) 2015 botmonster@7items.com

 Licensed under the MIT license:
   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

 Project home:
   http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/

 Version:  1.0.7

*/
(function(h,q){h.fn.bootpag=function(p){function m(c,b){b=parseInt(b,10);var d,e=0==a.maxVisible?1:a.maxVisible,k=1==a.maxVisible?0:1,n=Math.floor((b-1)/e)*e,f=c.find("li");a.page=b=0>b?0:b>a.total?a.total:b;f.removeClass(a.activeClass);d=1>b-1?1:a.leaps&&b-1>=a.maxVisible?Math.floor((b-1)/e)*e:b-1;a.firstLastUse&&f.first().toggleClass(a.disabledClass,1===b);e=f.first();a.firstLastUse&&(e=e.next());e.toggleClass(a.disabledClass,1===b).attr("data-lp",d).find("a").attr("href",g(d));k=1==a.maxVisible?
0:1;d=b+1>a.total?a.total:a.leaps&&b+1<a.total-a.maxVisible?n+a.maxVisible+k:b+1;e=f.last();a.firstLastUse&&(e=e.prev());e.toggleClass(a.disabledClass,b===a.total).attr("data-lp",d).find("a").attr("href",g(d));f.last().toggleClass(a.disabledClass,b===a.total);e=f.filter("[data-lp="+b+"]");k="."+[a.nextClass,a.prevClass,a.firstClass,a.lastClass].join(",.");if(!e.not(k).length){var m=b<=n?-a.maxVisible:0;f.not(k).each(function(b){d=b+1+n+m;h(this).attr("data-lp",d).toggle(d<=a.total).find("a").html(d).attr("href",
g(d))});e=f.filter("[data-lp="+b+"]")}e.not(k).addClass(a.activeClass);l.data("settings",a)}function g(c){return a.href.replace(a.hrefVariable,c)}var l=this,a=h.extend({total:0,page:1,maxVisible:null,leaps:!0,href:"javascript:void(0);",hrefVariable:"{{number}}",next:"&raquo;",prev:"&laquo;",firstLastUse:!1,first:'<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>',last:'<span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>',wrapClass:"pagination",activeClass:"active",disabledClass:"disabled",nextClass:"next",prevClass:"prev",
lastClass:"last",firstClass:"first"},l.data("settings")||{},p||{});if(0>=a.total)return this;h.isNumeric(a.maxVisible)||a.maxVisible||(a.maxVisible=parseInt(a.total,10));l.data("settings",a);return this.each(function(){var c,b,d=h(this);c=['<ul class="',a.wrapClass,' bootpag">'];a.firstLastUse&&(c=c.concat(['<li data-lp="1" class="',a.firstClass,'"><a href="',g(1),'">',a.first,"</a></li>"]));a.prev&&(c=c.concat(['<li data-lp="1" class="',a.prevClass,'"><a href="',g(1),'">',a.prev,"</a></li>"]));for(b=
1;b<=Math.min(a.total,a.maxVisible);b++)c=c.concat(['<li data-lp="',b,'"><a href="',g(b),'">',b,"</a></li>"]);a.next&&(b=a.leaps&&a.total>a.maxVisible?Math.min(a.maxVisible+1,a.total):2,c=c.concat(['<li data-lp="',b,'" class="',a.nextClass,'"><a href="',g(b),'">',a.next,"</a></li>"]));a.firstLastUse&&(c=c.concat(['<li data-lp="',a.total,'" class="last"><a href="',g(a.total),'">',a.last,"</a></li>"]));c.push("</ul>");d.find("ul.bootpag").remove();d.append(c.join(""));c=d.find("ul.bootpag");d.find("li").click(function(){var b=
h(this);if(!b.hasClass(a.disabledClass)&&!b.hasClass(a.activeClass)){var c=parseInt(b.attr("data-lp"),10);l.find("ul.bootpag").each(function(){m(h(this),c)});l.trigger("page",c)}});m(c,a.page)})}})(jQuery,window);

$('document').ready(function(){
  
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading...
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
```

try manually hosting the bootpag.js file and calling it from there

Comment: Got the js from a different host and it's rendering correctly.

Comment: Actyally what you did is use the latest version `1.0.7`; looks like `1.0.4` that you were using before had a bug: https://github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/issues/26